# Remove a class from the whole page?

Tags: javascript

I want to remove a class from the whole page or just from the class "nav-link". I guess that's not working because it would make no sense to remove a class from a class,but yea

```
document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link").classList.remove("active");
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove all elements with that class name?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("active").classList.remove("active");` ?

Comment: That somehow  doesn't work:  Uncaught ReferenceError: removeAll is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: Please, make a snippet with your code. It could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove a particular class from all the elements, you gotta iterate through each element, and remove the class.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link').forEach(item => item.classList.remove('active'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Get elements by class list returns multiple elements, you should remove the class you want from each one of the resulting elements..

Answer (score 0):

Please try this... I have used window load function and My code is find Classname "active" and remove the class.

```js
$(window).on("load", function(){
  $(document).find(".active").removeClass("active");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navLink active">abc</div>
<div class="navLink2 active">abc</div>
<div class="navLink3 active">abc</div>
<div class="navLink4 active">abc</div>
```

Comment: Ishita, first of all, there is no tag added for jQuery, so you are supposed to provide JavaScript solution. Besides that, there is no condition given that the action has to take place on `load` event. And last thing, there might be several elements having class `active`. So finding elements, on the basis of presence of `active` class is not right in itself :)